# Using Grails Gradle plugin on Ubuntu: Grails not found

Tags: grails, gradle

I am currently trying to build a Grails project using Gradle to easily integrate some repositories. I have created a new directory, and from said directory I have created the following build.gradle file as instructed from this site:

http://grails.github.io/grails-gradle-plugin/docs/manual/guide/introduction.html

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        'org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'grails'

grails {
    grailsVersion = '2.4.0' // Specifies the Grails version to use
    groovyVersion = '2.3.1' // Specify the Groovy version to use (should match the version that ships with the above Grails version)
    springLoadedVersion = '1.2.0.RELEASE' // Specify the Spring Loaded version to use
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    grails.central() //Adds the Grails Central Repository for resolving Grails plugins (replaces grailsPlugins(), grailsCentral() from BuildConfig.groovy)
}

dependencies {
    bootstrap 'org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.50.1'

    compile 'org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.0.2'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.1'

    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:hibernate:3.6.10.8' //or 'org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.1.1'
    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.3.8'
    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.0'
    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.2'

    //runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'
    //runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3.1100-jdbc41'

    //Additional resources capabilities
    //runtime 'org.grails.plugins:zipped-resources:1.0.1'
    //runtime 'org.grails.plugins:cached-resources:1.1'
    //runtime 'org.grails.plugins:yui-minify-resources:0.1.5'

    //Alternate to the resources plugin
    //compile 'org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:1.5.0'

    //Additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile 'org.grails.plugins:sass-asset-pipeline:1.5.1'
    //compile 'org.grails.plugins:less-asset-pipeline:1.5.0'
    //compile 'org.grails.plugins:coffee-asset-pipeline:1.5.0'
    //compile 'org.grails.plugins:handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.0.0.3'
}
```

When I try to build using `gradle init`, I am confronted with this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/ian/grailsDir/deadness/build.gradle' line: 10
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'deadness'.

  > Plugin with id 'grails' not found.

How can I get the Grails plugin? I am currently running Grails 2.5.0 and Gradle 2.4. I tried it with an earlier version of Grails as well.

The stacktrace is:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'deadness'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:76)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$1.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:156)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:487)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'grails' not found.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware$apply.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_cgy5iob1jp300dugadkqvpnyl.run(/home/ian/grailsDir/deadness/build.gradle:10)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:74)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: Have you tried to use maven central repositories? `mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }`

Answer (score 4):

Please, note that the following code...

```
dependencies {
    'org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
}
```

...should be:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
}
```

This must solve the issue.

Comment: looks like this was taken from the quickstart build.gradle which does not declare "classpath": http://grails.github.io/grails-gradle-plugin/docs/manual/guide/introduction.html#quickstart